# How to Find 6-Digit Barcodes in a Column

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

So, I have a spreadsheet with a column of barcodes that should be 6 digits long, like this A02938 (a letter with 5 numbers after it), but sometimes another digit is added by mistake, turning it into something like this A024938. So, my question is this...

**How can I highlight the cell if it contains more than 6 digits?**

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I would recommend the same method as answered however use the built in operator of `Is not equal to` in the drop down menu. So it highlights if it's more than 6 digits, or less than. Of course this can always be formulated if you prefer a custom formula like the answer provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Go to `Format` > `Conditional Formatting`
2. In apply to range select the column where you have the barcodes.
   For example (A:A)
3. In format rules, select the dropdown-menu option `Custom formula is` and add
   `=LEN(A:A) > 6`
4. Choose the formatting style you prefer below

[image]